# Execute different methods depending on the data

Tags: python

I'm trying to have my program take in a variable and execute one of two methods, depending on whether it's a `string` or `int`.

I got the following code from stack overflow:

```
x = 1
print(type(x))
```

But how can I do something like this?

```
x = 1
if (type(x) == integer):
    doSomeThing()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
x=1 #or x='hello'

if type(x)==int:
    doSomething()
elif type(x)==str:
    doSomethingElse()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check type of instance through isinstance() function

```
x = 1
if isinstance(x, (int,)):
    print("x is integer")
else:
    print(f"x is {type(x).__name__}")
```

Comment: The checked type `int` shouldn't be wrapped in a tuple. Also, instead of `type(x).__name__` you can use `x.__class__`

Comment: @C.Nivs: the tuple is actually fine (if extraneous); `isinstance` can take the second argument as a tuple of types, and would return `True` is the first argument belongs to any of these types.

Comment: `x.__class__` will return type object. `x.__class__.__name__` will return name of type of object.

Comment: @C.Nivs and execute `help(isinstance)`

Comment: Use isinstance() to make check type of data which give you bool value use this value to run specific code.

Comment: @alex I guess lack of sleep is getting to me, good to go back to docs sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isinstace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) from python built-ins

```
x=1 #or x='hello'

if ininstance(x,int):
    doSomething()
elif ininstance(x,str):
    doSomethingElse()
```

Answer (score 0):

use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
x = 42 # 
if isinstance(x, int):
    your_int_method(x)
elif isinstance(x, str):
    your_str_method(x)
else:
    # what's else?
    ...
```

If you want something like JS behavior if you want to process strings which are numbers (like "42") you can add additional checking under `isinstance(x, str):` scope.